# Paddle reflect ball depending on contact point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When hitting paddle ball is bouncing weird.

```
private Vector3 direction;

private void Start()
{
    direction = transform.up;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.Translate(direction * (Time.deltaTime * BallManager.Instance.initialBallSpeed));
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Paddle"))
    {
        var cp = col.contacts[0];
        direction = Vector2.Reflect(direction, PaddleScript.Instance.transform.position.normalized);
    }
}
```

I want to make to bounce with always same force up and to side depending on hit point.

Comment: It looks like you're using transform.Translate instead of Rigidbody.velocity so you can't really deal with force. Also, it's hard to conceptualize what your issue is without more examples.

Comment: I want to calculate vector of direction to moving ball depending on hit point on paddle.

Comment: Well divide the paddle. Check impact. Check ball velocity. Send out on angle accordingly

Answer (score 0):

First of all when using Physics you shouldn't go through `Transform` at all.

You wouldn't even need this component at all.. why not simply

- eliminate all gravity (`Gravity Scale` -> `0`)
- eliminate all drag (`Linear Drag` -> `0`)
- put a proper [`PhysicsMaterial2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsMaterial2D.html) on the ball and/or paddles colliders and set `bounciness` to `1` and friction to `0`

=> It should already behave as desired by default.

---

Otherwise I would change your code to

```
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
private Vector3 direction;

private void Start()
{
    if(!rigidbody) rigidbody= GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    direction = transform.up;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rigidbody.MovePosition(rigidbody.position + direction * Time.deltaTime * BallManager.Instance.initialBallSpeed);
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Paddle"))
    {
        var cp = col.contacts[0];
        // and then you want to reflect on the normal of the contact..
        // a normalized position doesn't make any sense in this context
        direction = Vector2.Reflect(direction, cp.normal);
    }
```

or if you wanted to add the variance depending on where the ball hits the paddle I would put an object at each tip of the paddle and then you can [inverse lerp](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1271974/inverselerp-for-vector3.html)

```
public static class Vector2Extensions
{
    public static float InverseLerp(thjs Vector2 value, Vector2 min, Vector2 max)
     {
         var direction = max - min;
         var AV = value - min;
         return Mathf.Clamp01(Vector2.Dot(AV, direction) / Vector2.Dot(direction, direction));
     }
}
```

to check whether your hit contact is closer to left (0) or right (1) tip or exactly in the center (0.5) and according to this factor add some min/max angle offset to the vector. e.g. using plain reflect as before when exactly in the center and then add some rotation according to the offset factor from above e.g. using

```
direction = Vector2.Reflect(direction, cp.normal);

// this will return a dynamic factor of whether the contact is closer to left (0), right (1) or in the middle (0.5) 
var inverseLerp = cp.point.InverseLerp(leftTip, rightTip);

// this will map the inverseLerp factor which goes between `0` and `1` 
// to the added angle offset which goes from -30° to 30°
var angle = Mathf.Lerp(-30, 30, inverseLerp);
direction = (Vector2)(Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle) * direction);
```

If you want you could even remove the `Reflect` entirely and then not add a rotation to the direction but rather hard replace it with a new direction based on the same lerp as before